# Gettings list of files USMT will capture

Tags: windows-xp, usmt

I would like to make a list of all the files that USMT will capture.  The purpose for this, is that I'd like to provide that list to a user before their migration to Win7 which details which files will be backed up.  I want them to be able to review it before actually wiping their system.

I first tried the /genmigxml switch which uses the Document Finder.  It does work in finding files it would backup, but it provides no means that I know of to configure it.  I cannot provide it the MigApp.xml or the MigDocs.xml files to add or remove the list of files that it is capturing.  It simply captures the same list of files and takes no additional switches.

I then tried the /genconfig switch which generates a config.xml file.  It takes multiple input xmls and spits out another xml, but the resulting xml file doesn't actually have files and folders listed.  For example, it only states that it will backup Firefox, but doesn't state which files and folders are apart of that.

The only other option I could think of is to actually use USMT to migrate data locally and use the /listfiles switch to get a list of the files that are being backed up.  That seems like a terrible way to handle this.

I would like another option to address this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ScanState.exe c:\store /p:c:\spaceRequirements.xml /listfiles:FileName
```

While the store is required it's not created and you will also get a size estimate.  You can certianly specify whatever files you like to include using the /i and providing a custom XML file, see [Include Files and Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560778%28WS.10%29.aspx).

I agree that this is a horrible way to approach this.  You should be communicating the migration to the users and having them place the data in the my documents folder. Especially since even if I gave you a list that I'm going to migrate, when I discover that "Rob's super secret doc" isn't on it and you ask me what to do, the answer is going to be "put it in your documents folder"  The document finder should find anything **they've** missed, and the custom xml files for any files or settings not normally included (eg lotus notes data files, firefox settings etc).

Comment: This got me down the right path.  For whatever reason I couldn't specify the p switch with an XML file along with the listfiles switch.  It would however let me use /p /nocompress /listfiles:output.txt

Comment: That's odd, /p needs something to write to... I'm glad it worked in any case

Comment: apparently it is there for compatibility for version 3.0.  It writes USMTSize.txt to the store you specify.  In order to pass the p switch on its own you also have to use the nocompress switch.  Thanks again for the help.